# How do you use the ResponseCacheControl URL parameter in Amazon?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, caching

According to the [Amazon S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html#API_GetObject_RequestSyntax), there is a query parameter called `ResponseCacheControl` that can be added to an S3 URL so that the response includes a `Cache-Control` header, which I need so that my browser will cache the response i.e I need it to return with

`Cache-Control: max-age=100`

However, the notoriously terrible Amazon S3 docs don't give any information on how to use this parameter!

Does anyone know, what value do I give it to get back the response with the desired header?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html#API_GetObject_Example_9

Answer (score 0):

To use `max-age`, you need to URL encode it.

```
response-cache-control=max-age%3D100
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work. It result in `403` errors from Amazon